# Can I run a stored lambda whose captured values are no longer in scope?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++-amp

I have a future to which I want to pass a lambda to run when it is complete, but the scope will have changed by the time the lambda executes; what happens to the captured value? For example

```
bool* MakeThen(Concurrency::completion_future& future)
{
  bool * isFinished = new bool(false);
  future.then([=](){ *isFinished = true; });

  return isFinished;
}
```

By the time that lambda actually executes, the function might have finished. So what will happen? Is capturing by value just like binding a bunch of variables?

Comment: `*bool = true;`?  Or `*isFinished = true;`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley sorry that was supposed to be `*isFinished = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda captures the `isFinished` pointer by value, and the object to which it points is on the free store.  So it's fine.  There is no local object being referred to in the lambda.

Comment: So once the lambda is defined, it is "bound" to the value and will not "request" it again on call?

Comment: @ausairman: Correct, unless you capture by reference obviously.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you haven't done `delete isFinished;`, it's safe.